# Bind problem in SQL query in Node, Express, Mysql2 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mysql2

I have been following a [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-express-js-mysql-rest-api-example/) on setting up REST APIs in Node, using Express for an app that accesses an existing MariaDB database. My version only needs to read data and I have the DB co-located with the Node application (same host).

My goal for this entry-level example is to just access the data, using static SQL, so I can see it rendered in the web page by the JSON pritifier.

[Next, I want to present the data in a table (EJS?). Later, when I can get that to work, I'll add form controls (React?) to let a user specify start and end date bounds for the SQL query. Finally I'll aim to render the data as a line graph (D3js).]

The tutorial runs the web server successfully (it returns 'OK' on the base URL), but when I go to URL/solarData it tries an async function to getMultiple rows from the DB, it responds:

```
Bind parameters must not contain undefined. To pass SQL NULL specify JS null TypeError: Bind parameters must not contain undefined. To pass SQL NULL specify JS null
    at /SunnyData/solarViz/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:628:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.execute (/SunnyData/solarViz/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:620:22)
    at /SunnyData/solarViz/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:120:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at PromiseConnection.execute (/SunnyData/solarViz/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:117:12)
    at Object.query (/SunnyData/solarViz/services/db.js:6:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object.getMultiple (/SunnyData/solarViz/services/solarData.js:7:16)
    at async /SunnyData/solarViz/routes/solarData.js:8:14
app.js:61
```

**./app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3800;
const solarDataRouter = require('./routes/solarData');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({'message': 'ok'});
})

app.use('/solarData', solarDataRouter);

/* Error handler middleware */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  console.error(err.message, err.stack);
  res.status(statusCode).json({'message': err.message});


  return;
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

**./routes/solarData.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const solarData = require('../services/solarData');

/* GET solar data. */
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    res.json(await solarData.getMultiple(req.query.page));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error while getting solar data `, err.message);
    next(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

**./config.js**

```
const env = process.env;

const config = {
  db: { 
    host: env.SUNNY_HOST,
    user: env.SUNNY_USER,
    password: env.SUNNY_PW,
    database: env.SUNNY_DB,
  },
  listPerPage: env.LIST_PER_PAGE,
};

module.exports = config;
```

**./services/solarData.js**

```
const db = require('./db');
const helper = require('../helper');
const config = require('../config');

async function getMultiple(page = 1){
  const offset = helper.getOffset(page, config.listPerPage);
  const rows = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM DTP LIMIT ?,?`, [offset, config.listPerPage]
  );
  const data = helper.emptyOrRows(rows);
  const meta = {page};

  return {
    data,
    meta
  }
}
module.exports.getMultiple = getMultiple;
```

**./services/db.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const config = require('../config');

async function query(sql, params) {
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config.db);
  const [results, ] = await connection.execute(sql, params);

  return results;
}

module.exports = {
  query
}
```

I've left out the ./helper.js

Everything runs fine until I direct the webpage to /solarData. At that point I get the Debug Console (vscode) mentioned up-front

Searching seems to point at a mysql2 shortcoming/bug but not at a practical solution
If you respond, please describe the 'bind' mechanism, as I'm not sure what's going on.

Hope I've put enough info in. Please ask if I need to add anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

> Bind parameters must not contain undefined.

It means that in the file **./services/solarData.js** on the line

```
const rows = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM DTP LIMIT ?,?`, [offset, config.listPerPage]
  );
```

Some of the 2 variables is undefined, you need to check **offset** and **config.listPerPage** to be defined.

Just use

```
console.log('offset: ' + offset)
console.log('listPerPage: ' + config.listPerPage)
```

and you will find out what is undefined in your case

Comment: Thanks Dmitrii. Seems you were correct. LIST_PER_PAGE was undefined because `config.js`, which is meant to pick up the environment variables isn't or, if it is, then `./services/solarData.js`, isn't correctly expressing them. The same problem occurs for all of the environment variables in `config.js`. They exist in the environment - checked via ssh, e.g. `echo $SUNNY_DB` ---> `SunnyData2`

Comment: Replace listPerPage from listPerPage: env.LIST_PER_PAGE to listPerPage: env.LIST_PER_PAGE || 10

Comment: Or just write 10 instead of config.listPerPage in ./services/solarData.js

Comment: I `module.exports = config;` from config.js
Then I `const config = require('../config');` from ./services/solarData.js

In SolarData.js, if I want to use an environment variable from `config`, is it, for example, `config.host` (using the assigned variable name from the `config` module?

Comment: I have just added the `||` directive to all my config, with cleartext values for access to my DB and it does give me access to the data but leaves it very vulnerable, so I'm really keen to get the `process.env` method working - I think it's down to how I extract the values in `./services/solarData.js`

Comment: Yes, you should start node js using the following command `LIST_PER_PAGE=10 node app.js`, however, better all the time to put an alternative value for the case a program cannot find a variable in the env. So, it is better to write `listPerPage: env.LIST_PER_PAGE || 10`  in ./config.js, if something goes wrong with the environment the default value will be 10 (for example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236568/discussion-between-dmitrii-and-greg).